# json to mysql via pandas and pymysql

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

I'm currently working on a real-time json via python
my idea : 
- extract and wrangle json via pandas python (did it : about 3720 x 15 df)
- convert dataframe to tables in mysql (using pymysql on windows)

my code :

```
dfc=dfc.values.tolist()
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db="decaux",
                             charset='utf8mb4')

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for rows in dfc:
        sql7="insert into contracts(id,contract_name,commercial_name) values(%s, %s, %s)"
        data = (rows[0],rows[1],rows[2])
        cursor.execute(sql7,data)
```

but nothing happen...
what did I do wrong ?
Is there a better idea ?